# C++ compile error: undefine reference to 'printMaze(int const(*)[16],int,int)' and Id returned 1 exit status

Tags: c++, c++11

**I have already got answer of this question now I edit this question to help others for understanding this problem**

For some reason, when I try to compiling a program, the compiler says errors undefine reference to 'printMaze(int const(*)[16],int,int)' and Id returned 1 exit status.
Thank you

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

void printMaze(const int maze[][16], int xLoc, int yLoc);
int mazeTraverse(int maze[][16], int xLoc, int yLoc, int facing);

int main()
{
    int maze[ 9 ][ 16 ] = {
{42,  42,   42,  42, 42,  42,  42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42,  42,  42,  42, 42},
{42,   0,    0,  0,  -1,   0,   0,  0, -1,  0, -1,  0,   0,  0,    0, 42},
{42,  -1,   -1,  0,  -1,  -1,  -1,  0, -1,  0, -1,  0,  -1, -1,   -1, 42},
{42,  -1,   -1,  0,  -1,  -1,  -1,  0, -1,  0, -1,  0,  -1, -1,   -1, 42},
{42,   0,    0,  0,   0,   0,  -1,  0,  0,  0, -1,  0,   0,  0,    0, 42},
{42,   0,   -1, -1,  -1,   0,  -1,  0, -1,  0, -1,  0,  -1, -1,    0, 42},
{42,   90,   -1, -1,  -1,   0,  -1,  0, -1,  0, -1,  0,  -1, -1,    0, 42}, 
{42,   0,   -1,  0,   0,   0,   0,  0, -1,  0,  0,  0,  -1, -1,    80, 42},
{42,  42,   42,  42, 42,  42,  42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42,  42,  42,   42, 42}
};


int success = 0;

    success = mazeTraverse(maze, 7, 14, 1); // Call function to move through the maze, assign returned value to success.

    if (success == 1)   // If success is equal to 1...
        cout << "Congratulations! The maze has been solved.\n"; // ...output congratulations...
    else    // ...else...
        cout << "Unfortunately the maze has not been solved correctly.\n";  // ...output failed message.
    return 0; // End program.
}

// print the current state of the maze

void printMaze( const char maze[][ 16 ], int xLoc, int yLoc)
{
   // nested for loops to iterate through maze
   for ( int x = 0; x < 9; ++x ) 
   {
      for ( int y = 0; y < 16; ++y )
          if ((x == xLoc) && (y == yLoc))
              cout << 'X' << ' ';
          else
              cout << maze[ x ][ y ] << ' ';

      cout << '\n';
   } // end for

   cout << "\nHit return to see next move\n";
   cin.get();
} // end function printMaze

// Traverse through the maze one square at a time
int mazeTraverse(int maze[][16], int xLoc, int yLoc, int facing)
{
    int success = 0;

    maze[xLoc][yLoc] = 1;   // Mark current location in the maze.

    printMaze(maze, xLoc, yLoc);    // Call function to display maze with current location marked.

    while (success == 0)    // While success is not equal to 0...
    {
        if ((xLoc == 6) && (yLoc == 1)) // If current location is the exit of the maze...
        {
            success = 1;    // ...set success to 1.
        }
        else if (facing == 0)   // Else if facing up...
        {
            if (maze[xLoc][yLoc+1] == 0)    // ...check square to the right for valid move...
            {
                success = mazeTraverse(maze, xLoc, yLoc+1, 1);  // Move to the right.
            }
            else if (maze[xLoc-1][yLoc] == 0)   // ...check square above for valid move...
            {
                success = mazeTraverse(maze, xLoc-1, yLoc, 0);  // Move up.
            }
            else if (maze[xLoc][yLoc-1] == 0)   // ...check square to the left for valid move...
            {
                success = mazeTraverse(maze, xLoc, yLoc-1, 3);  // Move to the left.
            }
            else    // If nowhere to go...
                return 0;   // ...close recursion to the previous junction.
        }
        else if (facing == 1)   // If facing right...
        {
            if (maze[xLoc+1][yLoc] == 0)    // ...check square below for valid move...
            {
                success = mazeTraverse(maze, xLoc+1, yLoc, 2);  // Move down.
            }
            else if (maze[xLoc][yLoc+1] == 0)   // ...check square to the right for valid move...
            {
                success = mazeTraverse(maze, xLoc, yLoc+1, 1);  // Move right.
            }
            else if (maze[xLoc-1][yLoc] == 0)   // ...check square above for valid move...
            {
                success = mazeTraverse(maze, xLoc-1, yLoc, 0);  // Move up.
            }
            else    // If nowhere to go...
                return 0;   // ...close recursion to the previous junction.
        }
        else if (facing == 2)   // If facing down...
        {
            if (maze[xLoc][yLoc-1] == 0)    // ...check square to the left for valid move...
            {
                success = mazeTraverse(maze, xLoc, yLoc-1, 3);  // Move to the left.
            }
            else if (maze[xLoc+1][yLoc] == 0)   // ...check square below for valid move...
            {
                success = mazeTraverse(maze, xLoc+1, yLoc, 2);  // Move down.
            }
            else if (maze[xLoc][yLoc+1] == 0)   // ...check square to the right for valid move...
            {
                success = mazeTraverse(maze, xLoc, yLoc+1, 1);  // Move to the right.
            }
            else    // If nowhere to go...
                return 0;   // ...close recursion to the previous junction.
        }
        else if (facing == 3)   // If facing left...
        {
            if (maze[xLoc-1][yLoc] == 0)    // ...check square above for valid move...
            {
                success = mazeTraverse(maze, xLoc-1, yLoc, 0);  // Move up.
            }
            else if (maze[xLoc][yLoc-1] == 0)   // ...check square to the left for valid move...
            {
                success = mazeTraverse(maze, xLoc, yLoc-1, 3);  // Move to the left.
            }
            else if (maze[xLoc+1][yLoc] == 0)   // ...check square below for valid move...
            {
                success = mazeTraverse(maze, xLoc+1, yLoc, 2);  // Move down.
            }
            else    // If nowhere to go...
                return 0;   // ...close recursion to the previous junction.
        }
    }   // ...end while loop.

    return success; // Return value of success.
}
```

Comment: And the error is ...?

Comment: error: Id returned 1 exit status

Comment: I means full error

Comment: Danh has certainly raised an obvious bug in your code.  But ld returning an error is likely something else.  What command are you using to compile and link?  If this is still on Windows, have you tried just restarting the computer?  This usually closes all open files.

Comment: Now that you have updated your question to include the full error, @Danh clearly has the answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

This is your declaration:

```
void printMaze(const int maze[][16], int xLoc, int yLoc);
```

and this is your definition:

```
void printMaze( const char maze[][ 16 ], int xLoc, int yLoc)
```

Change one of them to match with the other.

Comment: Thank you very much, Sir